# Should I separate my API tests from E2E tests

Tags: automated-testing, api-testing, test-strategy, e2e

I have a system that displays data it gets from API calls. There are multiple objects and every object has 7-8 properties. User is not allowed to change values and the system has a simple UI. I want to test that the correct data is represented in the UI. What should be the test strategy for this? I'm thinking of using Playwright framework.

What I have thought so far:

1. For every test case

   - making api request
   - asserting response
   - checking the values in UI

   It doesn't seem ideal.
2. - separating API tests
   - mocking API calls in UI testing

I don't know if it would give the confidence of real user experience.

3)

- separating API test
- UI only test (without validating data)
- applying no 1 for most important test cases

What is your suggestion?

Comment: I don't have much qa exp and company has limited resources so we want to focus on what could we do best. Sorry if i  misuse terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing mission:

> I want to test the correct data is represented on UI

The target system is the UI, so, you have to explore two aspects:

1 - Does my UI integrate correctly with the service(s)?
2 - Given that (1) holds, is the UI displaying the data correctly?

(1) can be tackled with [Contract Testing](https://pactflow.io/blog/what-is-contract-testing/).
In (2), you should have control over the inputs of your system (the UI), thus you can explore the data provided by the service(s) - this control comes from using test doubles, like mocks. Their acceptance tests and API documentation (e.g. OpenAPI) can be good source of ideas for what the services can provide.

Comment: Are you suggesting to test the UI and API server in seperation, with no integration tests at all?

Comment: I've talked about integration tests in (1). Pact will be used to checked if the expectations of the consumer are satisfied by the provider - aka it will will be used to test their Integration